# 3Sum How to be free of duplicated tuples when using the 2 pointers approach?

Tags: pointers, sum

Link of the original question: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

I sorted the array, then used a 2-pointers and O(n^2) approach to this question. The following code seems correct to me, but it did not passed Case #1:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:=
        nums.sort()
        tripl = []
        for i in range(0, len(nums)-2):
            target = 0
            left = i+1
            right = len(nums)-1
            while(left < right):
                currentSum = nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right]
                if currentSum < target:
                    left += 1
                elif currentSum > target:
                    right -= 1
                else:
                    tripl.append([nums[i], nums[left], nums[right]])
                    left += 1
                    right -= 1
        return tripl
```

> Can someone explain how to avoid duplicated in the tuples?
> [(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIFBF.png)]

Can someone explain how do you work from the case given by leetcode to debug? I'm new to leetcode, and would love to hear how people with more experience debug from the test cases.

Comment: You could avoid duplicates by making `tripl` a set, then returning `list(tripl)`.  Also, when you do `left +=1 ` or `right -= 1`, you should advance until you get to a different number.

Comment: You test by doing `print( Solution().threeSum( [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4] ))`.  The testing gets more involved when you get to the binary tree problems.  You need a way to translate their notation into a tree of nodes.